# Menú con scroll o scrolling en pantalla móvil o tableta no funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-4

He probado diversas maneras para que el menú con scroll me funcione, siempre en pantalla grande me funciona correctamente, pero cuando está en modo tableta o móvil y al hacer clic el menú, no se desplaza correctamente a la sección que debe ir.

Este es mi código:

Script en `<head>`

> Librería scrollpy

```
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
    smoothScroll.init({
        selector: '[data-scroll]',
        selectorHeader: null,
        speed: 2000,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        offset: 60,
        callback: function(anchor, toggle) {}
    });
</script>
```

Menú dentro del `<body>`:

```
<body class="deep-purple lighten-5" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navscroll" data-offset="60">
    <section class="container sticky-top">
        <nav id="navscroll" class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light mb-4 deep-purple lighten-5 STAZUL shadow-none">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                <img src="imagenes/" alt="" width="150" height="60">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-navicon" style="color:#0A448E; font-size:31px;"></i>
                </span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-center">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link STAZUL font-weight-bold menuactivo active rounded" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span><a> 
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold rounded nav-pills" data-scroll href="#menu1">Nosotros</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold rounded nav-pills" data-scroll href="#menu2">Servicios</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold rounded nav-pills " data-scroll href="#menu3">Cotización</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold rounded nav-pills " data-scroll href="#menu4">Contacto</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold rounded nav-pills disabled" href="#">Academia</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link font-weight-bold rounded nav-pills disabled" href="#">Blog</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>
</body>
```

Después, cada sección tiene su `id` o identificador desde la sección, en pantalla grande, funciona excelente, pero en tableta Y móvil, no funciona.

Comment: Gracias Art Eze por las correcciones.

Comment: A qué te refieres con que en móviles no funciona? No funciona en absoluto?

Comment: Hola Jheyman, el scrollspy funciona en pantalla grande LG boostrap pero en pantallas MD Y SM, se desplaza mas de lo normal o menos y no cae en el titulo de cada sección. pero lo he resuelto dando más espacio a las secciones, no se si hay otra manera. Gracias.-